# Android Kotlin return to setOnQueryTextListener

Tags: android, kotlin

Below is a android SerchView widget query handling. In which I apply a simple Validator. when `var success = true`, code passes. Otherwise return to  `setOnQueryTextListener`. But I cant do this properly. Here I used `return@setOnQueryTextListener`. But an error.

```
placeSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
            android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

            override fun onQueryTextChange(qString: String): Boolean {
                return true
            }
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(qString: String): Boolean {
                placeSearch.hideKeyboard()
                showProgress()
                var success = true
                val placeResult = Validator.Search.place(qString.trim())

                if (!placeResult.success){
                    context?.onError(getString(placeResult.message, placeResult.arg))
                    success = false
                }
                if (!success) {
                    hideProgress()
                    return@setOnQueryTextListner
                }

                loadLocations(false, qString)
                return true
            }
        })
```

Comment: `return true` will do the job.

Comment: `return@setOnQueryTextListner` doesn't make sense because the `OnQueryTextListener` is not a function to return from. It's an interface.

Comment: @Tenfour04, is `return true` do the job ?

Comment: You have to return true or false. True means your listener has handled the query and you don't want it to do its own default query, which is probably the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Have this extension function:

```
fun SearchView.setupQueryTextSubmit(callback: (String?) -> Unit) {
    setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            onTextSubmit.invoke(query)
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

And use it like so:

```
 searchView.setupQueryTextSubmit { text->
        //use here your text
    }
```